# "sudo: apt-get: command not found" on Ubuntu 17

Tags: apt, sudo

I can't use APT because of this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

If I run it without `sudo` I get `permission denied`, so what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` and `sudo /usr/bin/env` to your post, and as text. Please don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Since 16.04, you can use `apt` instead of `apt-get` -- have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Load the environment variables for your user with `. ~/$USER/.bashrc`.
2. Try using`sudo /usr/bin/apt-get update`, see if you get the same error.
3. If the above fails, become `root` and try executing the command.
4. If the 4th step fails, search the system to see if you have the `apt-get` binary: `sudo find / -name 'apt-get'`
5. If the binary is not found, maybe the system was not installed correctly.

Comment: saved hours of effort.